# Sitecore Rocks icons not loading in "Set Icon..." menu

Tags: sitecore-rocks, visual-studio

I can't select an icon from Sitecore Rocks "Set Icon.." menu, as the selection windows is always empty - previously it working fine.  I already tried restarting VS, Sitecore and my PC.

Thanks!

[image: Empty Sitecore Rocks menu[1]]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by updating to the latest version of Rocks, then restarting VS.

To update Rocks: -

- Right-click the connection name under 'Connections' in Sitecore Explorer
- from the menu choose "Connections" / "Update Server Components"
- Hit "Update All". At time of writing latest version was 2.1.88.0

Comment: My Sitecore Rocks was already in version 2.1.88.0, I tried to update it but it didn't help. I also tried reinstalling whole Sitecore Rocks (on the server and in VS) and still I can't see any icons :(

Comment: @Martynka This is definitely fixed in 2.1.88, are you using it on a machine with an active Internet connection as the icons are pulled from the GitHub repo?

Comment: @sitecorium Yes I have an access to the Internet on the dev machine. Can it be a case of proxy/firewall settings?